# form.io: Not rendering custom component

Tags: angular, formio

I am trying to use [form.io](https://form.io/#/) with a custom component called `MeComponent` but it is not rendering it. I am not able to figure out what I am missing. This is what I've tried.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormioModule } from "angular-formio";

import { FormSchemaService } from "./services/form-schema.service";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { MeComponent } from "./me/me.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MeComponent, AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormioModule],
  providers: [FormSchemaService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormSchemaService } from "./services/form-schema.service";
import { OnInit } from "@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks";
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public title = "Playing with form.io";
  public data = [];

  public formConfig = {
    submission: {
      data: {
        firstName: "Joe",
        lastName: "Smith"
      }
    },
    options: {
      alerts: {
        submitMessage: "Thank you for something."
      },
      errors: {
        message: "Something is not right. Please call 911."
      },
      hooks: {
        beforeSubmit: ($event, callback) => {
          console.log("form.io --> beforeSubmit: ", $event);
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(callback);
            // Callback with a possibly manipulated submission.
            //  callback("Something wen wrong", null);
            // callback(null, $event);
            callback(
              {
                message: "Something bad happened.",
                component: null
              },
              null
            );
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  constructor(private schemaService: FormSchemaService) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    const sub$ = this.schemaService.getFormSchema().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      sub$.unsubscribe();
    });
  }

  public onSubmit($event) {
    console.log($event);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<hr>
<formio [form]="data" (submit)="onSubmit($event)" [submission]="formConfig.submission" [options]="formConfig.options"></formio>
```

Here's the service which provides data:

**form-schema.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

import "rxjs/add/operator/delay";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";

const data = {
  title: "My Test Form",
  components: [
    {
      type: "textfield",
      input: true,
      tableView: true,
      inputType: "text",
      inputMask: "",
      label: "First Name",
      key: "firstName",
      placeholder: "Enter your first name",
      prefix: "",
      suffix: "",
      multiple: false,
      customClass: "text-loud",
      protected: false,
      unique: false,
      persistent: true,
      validate: {
        required: true,
        minLength: 2,
        maxLength: 10,
        pattern: "",
        custom: "",
        customPrivate: false
      },
      conditional: {
        show: "",
        when: null,
        eq: ""
      }
    },
    {
      type: "textfield",
      input: true,
      tableView: true,
      inputType: "text",
      inputMask: "",
      label: "Last Name",
      key: "lastName",
      placeholder: "Enter your last name",
      prefix: "",
      suffix: "",
      multiple: false,
      protected: false,
      unique: false,
      persistent: true,
      validate: {
        required: true,
        minLength: 2,
        maxLength: 10,
        pattern: "",
        custom: "",
        customPrivate: false
      },
      conditional: {
        show: "",
        when: null,
        eq: ""
      }
    },
    {
      input: true,
      tableView: true,
      label: "Country",
      key: "country",
      placeholder: "Select a country",
      data: {
        json: [
          {
            name: "Afghanistan",
            code: "AF",
            $$hashKey: "object:1299"
          },
          {
            name: "Åland Islands",
            code: "AX",
            $$hashKey: "object:1300"
          },
          {
            name: "Albania",
            code: "AL",
            $$hashKey: "object:1301"
          },
          {
            name: "Algeria",
            code: "DZ",
            $$hashKey: "object:1302"
          },
          {
            name: "American Samoa",
            code: "AS",
            $$hashKey: "object:1303"
          },
          {
            name: "AndorrA",
            code: "AD",
            $$hashKey: "object:1304"
          },
          {
            name: "Angola",
            code: "AO"
          },
          {
            name: "Anguilla",
            code: "AI"
          },
          {
            name: "Antarctica",
            code: "AQ"
          },
          {
            name: "Antigua and Barbuda",
            code: "AG"
          },
          {
            name: "Argentina",
            code: "AR"
          },
          {
            name: "Armenia",
            code: "AM"
          },
          {
            name: "Aruba",
            code: "AW"
          },
          {
            name: "Australia",
            code: "AU"
          },
          {
            name: "Austria",
            code: "AT",
          },
          {
            name: "Azerbaijan",
            code: "AZ"
          },
          {
            name: "Bahamas",
            code: "BS",
          },
          {
            name: "Somalia",
            code: "SO"
          },
          {
            name: "South Africa",
            code: "ZA"
          },
          {
            name: "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
            code: "GS"
          },
          {
            name: "Spain",
            code: "ES"
          },
          {
            name: "Sri Lanka",
            code: "LK"
          },
          {
            name: "Sudan",
            code: "SD"
          },
          {
            name: "Suriname",
            code: "SR"
          },
          {
            name: "Svalbard and Jan Mayen",
            code: "SJ"
          },
          {
            name: "Swaziland",
            code: "SZ"
          },
          {
            name: "Sweden",
            code: "SE"
          },
          {
            name: "Switzerland",
            code: "CH"
          },
          {
            name: "Syrian Arab Republic",
            code: "SY"
          },
          {
            name: "Taiwan, Province of China",
            code: "TW"
          },
          {
            name: "Tajikistan",
            code: "TJ"
          },
          {
            name: "Tanzania, United Republic of",
            code: "TZ"
          },
          {
            name: "Thailand",
            code: "TH"
          },
          {
            name: "Timor-Leste",
            code: "TL"
          },
          {
            name: "Togo",
            code: "TG"
          },
          {
            name: "Tokelau",
            code: "TK"
          },
          {
            name: "Tonga",
            code: "TO"
          },
          {
            name: "Trinidad and Tobago",
            code: "TT"
          },
          {
            name: "Tunisia",
            code: "TN"
          },
          {
            name: "Turkey",
            code: "TR"
          },
          {
            name: "Turkmenistan",
            code: "TM"
          },
          {
            name: "Turks and Caicos Islands",
            code: "TC"
          },
          {
            name: "Tuvalu",
            code: "TV"
          },
          {
            name: "Uganda",
            code: "UG"
          },
          {
            name: "Ukraine",
            code: "UA"
          },
          {
            name: "United Arab Emirates",
            code: "AE"
          },
          {
            name: "United Kingdom",
            code: "GB"
          },
          {
            name: "United States",
            code: "US"
          },
          {
            name: "United States Minor Outlying Islands",
            code: "UM"
          },
          {
            name: "Uruguay",
            code: "UY"
          },
          {
            name: "Uzbekistan",
            code: "UZ"
          },
          {
            name: "Vanuatu",
            code: "VU"
          },
          {
            name: "Venezuela",
            code: "VE"
          },
          {
            name: "Viet Nam",
            code: "VN"
          },
          {
            name: "Virgin Islands, British",
            code: "VG"
          },
          {
            name: "Virgin Islands, U.S.",
            code: "VI"
          },
          {
            name: "Wallis and Futuna",
            code: "WF"
          },
          {
            name: "Western Sahara",
            code: "EH"
          },
          {
            name: "Yemen",
            code: "YE"
          },
          {
            name: "Zambia",
            code: "ZM"
          },
          {
            name: "Zimbabwe",
            code: "ZW"
          }
        ],
        url: "",
        resource: "",
        custom: "",
        headers: [
          {
            value: "",
            key: ""
          }
        ]
      },
      dataSrc: "json",
      valueProperty: "code",
      defaultValue: "",
      refreshOn: "",
      filter: "none",
      authenticate: false,
      template: "<span>{{ item.name }}</span>",
      multiple: false,
      protected: false,
      unique: false,
      persistent: true,
      hidden: false,
      clearOnHide: true,
      validate: {
        required: true
      },
      type: "select",
      $$hashKey: "object:565",
      hideLabel: false,
      labelPosition: "top",
      tags: [],
      conditional: {
        show: "",
        when: null,
        eq: ""
      },
      lockKey: true,
      limit: ""
    },
    {
      input: true,
      label: "Submit",
      tableView: false,
      key: "submit",
      size: "lg",
      leftIcon: "",
      rightIcon: "",
      block: true,
      action: "submit",
      disableOnInvalid: true,
      theme: "primary",
      type: "button"
    },
    {
      type: "me", // MeComponent
      tableView: true,
      persistent: true,
      unique: false,
      protected: false,
      defaultValue: "",
      input: true
    }
  ]
};

@Injectable()
export class FormSchemaService {
  constructor() {}

  public getFormSchema(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of(data).delay(1000);
  }
}
```

**me.component.ts**

```
import { Formio } from "formiojs/full";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormioResourceService,
  FormioResourceViewComponent,
  FormioResourceConfig
} from "angular-formio/resource";
import { FormioAppConfig } from "angular-formio";

@Component({
  template: `
  <p>Me Component</p>
  `
})
export class MeComponent extends FormioResourceViewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public service: FormioResourceService,
    public config: FormioResourceConfig
  ) {
    super(service, config);
    console.log(service, config);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("MeComponent --> ", this.service.resource);
  }
}

Formio.registerComponent("me", MeComponent);
```

Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Have you resolved this issue?,like creating a custom component

Answer (score 1):

The components that you register within `Formio.registerComponent` are not Angular components, but rather components that must derive from the `BaseComponent` found @ https://github.com/formio/formio.js/blob/master/src/components/base/Base.js.

Because of this, your code for the custom component will be done outside of the Angular framework, but will still function when it is rendered using Angular. Here is an example.

```
import { BaseComponent } from 'formiojs/src/components/base/Base';
export class CustomComponent extends BaseComponent {
  elementInfo() {
    let info = super.elementInfo();
    info.type = 'input';
    info.changeEvent = 'input';
    return info;
  }
}

Formio.registerComponent('custom', CustomComponent);
```

Comment: Hi Travis, Thanks for the answer. Is there any way I can register angular component which has it's own styles and template(supplied using `Component` decorator)? Or do I have to create it manually by overriding `build` function of `BaseComponent` and then add listeners and styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { BaseComponent } from 'formiojs/build/components/base/Base';
import { Formio } from 'formiojs/full';

export class CustomComponent extends BaseComponent {
  rows: string;
constructor(component, options, data) {
super(component, options, data);
this.rows = "";

}
elementInfo() {
    let info = super.elementInfo();
    console.log('sddsd');
    info.type = 'input';
    info.changeEvent = 'input';

    return info;
  }
  build(){
    super.build();
    let ele = super.renderTemplate("<div id='custom'>name</div>", {});
    let element = super.getElement();
    element.appendChild(ele);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer rather than just posting code.

Comment: the above code is just to extend or create new custom component. To render it you have to initialize with following line in the constructor of component where you want to use form.io ...
Formio.registerComponent('custom', CustomComponent);

Comment: see this post for more detail: https://github.com/formio/angular-formio/issues/85

Comment: This import doesn't work.     ```import { BaseComponent } from 'formiojs/build/components/base/Base';```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your custom component in Formio, you have to register your component where it is being used(consumed), preferrably in the constructor of your angular component.
For e.g.:-

```
constructor(    
  ) {
      Formio.registerComponent('custom', CustomComponent);
     Formio.registerComponent('question', QuestionnaireComponent);
     Formio.registerComponent('autotext', AutoTextRendererComponent);
  }
```